# Is it necessary to use std::move? Isn't this already an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
    B* ptr;
    A(B* ptr_) : ptr(std::move(ptr_))
    {}
};

A myA(new B);
```

In this code, is it necessary to call std::move on ptr_? Is it not already an rvalue reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `ptr_` is not an rvalue reference, because it is a named variable
2. there's no need for `std::move`, but not because it is a rvalue, but because moving and copying normal pointer is exactly the same operation (`std::move(ptr_)` will *not* clear `ptr_`)

Comment: What if I used unique_ptr instead? Would std::move then make a difference?

Comment: yes - in case of `std::unique_ptr` code won't compile without `std::move` - `ptr_` still will not be an rvalue, so `ptr(ptr_)` would be a copy operation and that is blocked for `std::uniqu_ptr`

Comment: Thanks. Will accept your answer after 5 minutes are gone.